# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown menu creates extra carets in collapsed navbar

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

and having problem with `dropdown menu` in `collapsed navbar`.

By clicking the top-right button to open the menu, the menu can be opened in collapsed version.

An extra caret is only created when screen is collapsed enough to show collapsed version of navbar.

How to fix this problem to not see the extra caret above the dropdown menu?

I do not want to see strange upper caret above `Category` menu.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/inspired_jw/aBt89/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the default styles of the Bootstrap navigation. The easiest way to remove it is to override the style which creates this by placing this CSS class somewhere in the CSS that you load after bootstrap CSS files.

```
.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu:before, .nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu:after {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: both `::before` and `::after`  `display:none;` resolved my problem :) thanks

Comment: Yeah, I had a bit of a look, and it seems to that both are used in order to render the border correctly. So you have to overwrite both.I updated the answer to reflect this for those who come looking in the future.